# PHP Resize Multiple Images

Tags: php, html, image-resizing, image-upload

I have simple HTML Form so you can upload mutliple images. I want to resize all of the images and set their width to `235`. The code is working fine (resize image, and move it to the selected folder) without the `foreach` method. It's cool but my goal is to upload **MULTIPLE** images, resize them and finally move them into the selected folder. Any idea why it is not working with the `foreach` method?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Image Resize</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name='myImage' type='file' multiple />
            <input name='submit' type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`upload.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  if(is_array($_FILES)) {
    print_r($_FILES);
    foreach ($_FILES['myImage']['name'] as $key=>$val) {
      $image_tmp = $_FILES["myImage"]["tmp_name"][$key];
      $images_type = $_FILES["myImage"]["type"][$key];
      $source_properties = getimagesize($image_tmp);
      $image_type = $source_properties[2];
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
        $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_tmp);
        $target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id, $source_properties[0], $source_properties[1]);
        imagejpeg($target_layer, '/upload/img/'.substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7).''.date('YmdHis').'.'.basename($images_type));
      }
      elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF )  {
        $image_resource_id = imagecreatefromgif($image_tmp);
        $target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id, $source_properties[0], $source_properties[1]);
        imagegif($target_layer, '/upload/img/'.substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7).''.date('YmdHis').'.'.basename($images_type));
      }
      elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
        $image_resource_id = imagecreatefrompng($image_tmp);
        $target_layer = fn_resize($image_resource_id, $source_properties[0], $source_properties[1]);
        imagepng($target_layer, '/upload/img/'.substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7).''.date('YmdHis').'.'.basename($images_type));
      }
    }
  }
}
function fn_resize($image_resource_id, $width, $height) {
  $target_width = 235;
  $target_height = 200;
  $target_layer = imagecreatetruecolor($target_width, $target_height);
  imagecopyresampled($target_layer, $image_resource_id, 0, 0, 0, 0, $target_width, $target_height, $width, $height);
  return $target_layer;
}
header('Location: index.html');
?>
```